# Exit running script without exiting shell

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have a script library that uses a lot of `exit` commands if some condition occurs. Each time an exit is hit, the shell is closed.

I saw many answers regarding this question that suggest changing the script, but my scripts are 3rd party and I assume the authors didn't mean that the shell should close so I assume there is some other way to run.

How do I run these script so that only the script stops but the shell remains open. Currently I use `. script.sh`.

Comment: the important question is: do you need the output of the child process, or do you just want the main-shell to stay alive

Comment: @grunt Why are you *running* it with `. script.sh`?! `./script.sh` would do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of launching your script as `. script.sh`, you can launch it `bash script.sh`. When you launch it with `bash` then a child process for bash will be opened and your script will execute in the child shell and exit statements will make child shell closed and have no scope for parent shell or main shell.

Comment: good answere, but OP did not say what he inteds to do (see my comment in his question)

Comment: @clockw0rk I see your comment and I am waiting for OP response so I can add my input. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are sourcing the script library and want to use all functions defined by the script library without causing the shell to exit use nested subshell.

Example:

```
# script.sh contents
hello_exit() { 
    echo "hello"; 
    sleep 1; 
    exit 10; 
}

# YOUR SHELL
source script.sh

# Use subshell
(hello_exit)

# If you want to capture the output and error code
output=$(hello_exit)
rc=$?
```